# Show git branch icon in lightline

Tags: git, plugin-lightline

Here is my code from `.vimrc` but is not showing any icon near the branch name

I'm using

```
Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim' " Lightline UI
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'    " Git wrapper for Vim
Plug 'itchyny/vim-gitbranch' " Show branch in buffer
```

```
let g:lightline = {
      \ 'colorscheme': 'dracula',
      \ 'active': {
      \   'left': [ [ 'mode', 'paste' ],
      \             [ 'gitbranch', 'readonly', 'filename', 'modified' ] ]
      \ },
      \ 'component_function': {
      \   'gitbranch': 'FugitiveHead'
      \ },
      \ 'component_prefix': {
      \   'gitbranch': '\uf126 '
      \ },
        \ 'tabline': {
      \   'left': [ ['buffers'] ],
      \   'right': [ ['close'] ]
      \ },
      \ 'component_expand': {
      \   'buffers': 'lightline#bufferline#buffers'
      \ },
      \ 'component_type': {
      \   'buffers': 'tabsel'
      \ }
      \ }

autocmd BufWritePost,TextChanged,TextChangedI * call lightline#update()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found no trace of `component_prefix` in the documentation or in the code of `lightline`.

I would propose you to do the following:

```
function MyFugitiveHead()
  let head = FugitiveHead()
  if head != ""
    let head = "\uf126 " .. head
  endif
  return head
endfunction

let g:lightline = {
    \ 'active': {
    \   'left': [ [ 'mode', 'paste' ],
    \             [ 'gitbranch', 'readonly', 'filename', 'modified' ] ]
    \ },
    \ 'component_function': {
    \   'gitbranch': 'MyFugitiveHead'
    \ },
    \}
```

Remark: This solution doesn't requires 'itchyny/vim-gitbranch'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for fixing the code!

Comment: You are welcome :-) Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Presumably this requires a "Nerd" font, since my font (and a few others I've tried) doesn't have the glyph for `\uf126`